# Is there a universal language?

Tags: java, ios, windows, macos, apache-flex

We're designing an app that will run on Windows, OSX, iOS, and Androids. It would be really nice to at least have most of the code in a single language rather than having to use Objective C for the Apple versions, C# or C++ for Windows, and Java for Android.

We were looking at Flex (with all of its problems) as a way to avoid having to use a different language for each version, but Adobe has thrown in the towel and in the long run that's not going to do the job. Java used to promise to be universal, but it looks like Apple no longer supports it as a part of the distributed OS, and as far as I can tell Microsoft never supported it. We don't want our users to have to download and install something just so they can use our app.

Is there a solution?  Or are we stuck with building the app in multiple languages?

Comment: There are compilers for the common languages on most platforms. The greater issue is a cross-platform framework.

Comment: One thing to note, is its not what language it is, its what the compiler compiles to. Logically, the question should be, is there a universal compiler, that would compile {put language here} to anything.

Comment: java for everything but iOS is an easy solution although the GUI is different for each platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"global" languages are most likely to use virtual machines, so you can't escape the "users have to have to download and install something just so they can use the app"... I think Java is your best bet if you don't want to deal with problems of languages that compiles into native machine code.

Comment: OK, that's pretty much what I thought. I'm guessing there is significant resistance to installing the Java runtime on Windows especially. As I understand it everything up to Lion for Macs comes with Java, but I don't think iOS has it. It would be a slam dunk on Android, of course.

Comment: BTW, I didn't tought about what Russell said... but there's actually a SDK that I met some weeks ago called mosync (http://mosync.com). They said that you can write HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript and C++ code and compile them into native applications (each platform generates a different file extension like android.apk, windows .exe etc.). You can give a try... I'm not using it because I'm currently using PhoneGap library that is integrated with Dreamweaver CS5, so I can't tell you more.

Comment: Very interesting. We also need apps on Windows and OSX, can we do that with mosync?

Comment: Actually yes, but you'll need an apple developer account. If I'm not wrong, mosync will generate the xcode project for you then you can just open and compile it in a OSX environment.

Answer (score 16):

HTML + css + JavaScript!

Run your app on a standard web server. All of the above have standards compliant web browsers, all of the above support JavaScript and AJAX. The only thing that really varies is screen size and this can easily be dealt with by using a custom .css file for each target browser.

Comment: I voted for this answer, but consider targeting device functionality over browser sniffing to serve CSS

Comment: We need to have an actual app that is downloaded. We may do what you suggest in terms of much of the actual functionality, but we still need an app that doesn't look like yet another browser for people to download.

Comment: You could embed your app within the "Jetty" web server.

Answer (score 8):

You could host a web application on a server and use the app browsers to interact with the application.

Although not a native application, all devices would be able to use it.

The downside is that server connectivity would be required, however this may not be an issue.

Comment: We may end up having to go with this, but we still have to have a native app for each platform.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use C# on all those platforms:

- "Normal" .NET on Windows
- [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) on OSX
- [MonoDroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) on Android
- [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) for iOS

(If you ever wanted to write an app for Windows Phone 7, you'd be fine there too.)

Of course the UI part will have to change significantly between different platforms, and I doubt that it'll be particularly *seamless*, but it's worth considering at least.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware of Mono.  However, if I understand correctly it still requires downloading a runtime, and I'd bet there will be considerable resistance to doing that on Apple products.

Comment: @user792826: You may be able to embed it with your application; I'm not sure. It would almost certainly increase the size requirements over a native app though.

Answer (score 2):

i am not very sure, but i have heard python is a universal language. I have tried this with both mac and windows, not sure about the other plactforms

Answer (score 2):

I believe C++ code can be run on all those platforms: Windows has full support for it; Android has NDK; and you can use Objective-C++ on iOS (and I assume OSX as well!).

I wouldn't go so far as to claim it's the best option, but I figured it was worth mentioning.

Ultimately a lot will depend on the nature of the app you are developing. If it's a large app I'd strongly suggest doing some detailed consultation with someone with experience in the area: because of the vagaries of the different platforms, this is one area where experience counts for an awful lot.

Comment: Objective C is similar to but not the same as C++. It is possible to run C++ code on OSX (and, I believe, iOS), but the entire UI architecture is different.  What I'm really looking for is a way to use the same code on all machines, it looks like that's not an option.

Comment: If you want to build a native app then you're always going to have to write <i>some</i> platform-specific code. Working in C++ would allow you to have common core code, but you'd have to roll your own API to interface with the different platforms. I've worked on successful projects that have done so, but there's a lot of work involved in building the API. As I suggested though, it's probably not the best option, especially if you're only writing the one app.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options, depending on your app requirements:

**First**, Web app, as many said before. It is the same as the greatest common divisor - very small

**Second** Build the core of your app in c/c++, and for the interface use a framework that fits your needs. These [suggestions](http://www.shervinemami.co.cc/phoneDevelopment.html) are really, really great. You can even develop the interface separately for each platform, in Java for Android, Objective C for iOS, etc

Do not forget that never, ever you will be able to make the same code run on all platforms. There will always be some part with `#define MAC` or `#define ANDROID`. It's just impossible to run identical code, even for the simplest app.

Unless is a

```
void main(void){}
```

Even a web app will have a code like

```
if(browser()==Safari) {}
else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on what kind of app you are going to build.

If it's like twitter, a good web interface is the answer. Each client just need to handle the GUI work, with the platform's own language and lib.

If it's a game, no communication with server. I prefer C and a script such as Lua to build the core of your app.

"Is there a solution? Or are we stuck with building the app in multiple languages?"

No, no solution for this. We use different languages because they run in different platforms.  Universal languages, such as HTML, have lots of constrains because to be universal you must cut all the differences. It is the intersection set of all platforms, which is very very small .

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML and Javascript is likely to be the best approach. Another option which runs on these platforms is Java FX 2.0.

Comment: Apple hates Java, hence no java for iphone/pad. I pity every day the iOS developers. The syntax and method signature length in objective-c is beyond awkward.